# I'm getting this error when I run my Spring backend: 405 Method Not Allowed Request method 'PUT' not supported

Tags: java, spring, backend

This is my controller class, it compile and run normally but doing the put request from Postman I get the 405 error. I have the POST and GET method working fine but the PUT and DELETE, not. url is http://localhost:8080/tweets

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/tweets")
public class TweetController {

@Autowired
private TweetRepository tweets;
private TweetRepository tweetRepository;

@GetMapping
public List<Tweet> listar() {

    return tweets.findAll();

}

@GetMapping ("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Tweet> buscar(@PathVariable Long id) {

    Optional<Tweet> tweet = tweets.findById(id);

    if (tweet.isEmpty()) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok(tweet.get());
}

@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Tweet adicionar(@Valid @RequestBody Tweet tweet) {
    Optional<Tweet> tweetExistente = tweets
            .findByNomeAndTexto(tweet.getNome(), tweet.getTexto());

    if (tweetExistente.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Existing data");
    }

    return tweets.save(tweet);
}


@PutMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<Object> editar(@RequestBody Tweet tweet, @PathVariable long id) {

    Optional<Tweet> tweetOptional = tweetRepository.findById(id);

    if (!tweetOptional.isPresent())
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

    tweet.setId(tweet.getId());
    tweet.setNome(tweet.getNome());
    tweet.setTexto(tweet.getTexto());

    tweetRepository.save(tweet);

    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void deletar(@PathVariable long id) {
    tweetRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

The output must be this:
{
    "timestamp": "2019-11-22T12:53:32.290+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'PUT' not supported",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' not supported\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:421)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:449)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:67)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:393)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1234)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)\n",
    "path": "/tweets"
}

Comment: Please add the output of the postman console to your question. Is there any additional request mapping on you controller?

Comment: Please add the whole class (is there another @RequestMapping on the class?) and the url you are calling...

Comment: Why do you have two `TweetRepository` instances in your controller class? I think the problem might be because you autowired `tweets` and didn't autowired `tweetRepository` (which you are using in PUT and DELETE methods)

Comment: Please check whether you have any CORS setup or Spring security configuration which doesn't allow certain methods or allow only certain methods such as GET, POST etc.

Comment: I fixed the @Autowired question getting only one TweetRepository and replacing it on both methods, but that error continues... I`ll see the CORS question now

Comment: Checked CORS, continues to fail... the interesting is that the others methods are working

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a typo in the path name. It was `@DeleteMapping("/department/{id}")` but should've been `@DeleteMapping("/departments/{id}")`